# Differences and relationship between yammer & codahale & dropwizard Metrics?

Tags: java, dropwizard, metrics

Metrics can measure some useful fields, but what's the differences and relations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all the same, but Dropwizard Metrics is the current library name

> Coda Hale Yammer Inc.

http://metrics.dropwizard.io

Another thing to look at is that the Maven dependencies for codahale metrics are latest in 2014 and Dropwizard are updated recently

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked at Maven central repo and found that both yammer & codahale Metrics have notations like that: "This artifact was moved to: New Group io.dropwizard.metrics".

Answer (score 2):

From Ryan Kennedy, formerly a Director of Engineering @ Yammer, [posted on the `dropwizard-user` group](https://groups.google.com/g/dropwizard-user/c/1usH7frpnZE/m/RSQUsOBFMsoJ):

> Long story short…metrics and dropwizard both started as Coda's personal projects. At some point they were important enough to the functioning of Yammer that we moved them to com.yammer. Eventually we reached a point where community participation was high enough that it made more sense to re-brand as io.dropwizard and put together a community of committers and maintainers. That brings us to where the projects are at today. I suspect package changing is now a thing of the past now that both projects are squarely in the hands of the community.

Going forward, I expect the Maven group name to stay as [`io.dropwizard.metrics`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics), the source code to live at [Github: dropwizard/metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics), and the Java package names to stay under `com.codahale.metrics`.